# openlayers kml with external styles

Tags: kml, openlayers

I'm trying to move my kml styles to an external document for use with OpenLayers. The styles work when they are included directly in the kml file.

At first I thought I could use straight kml for this with the styleUrl tag:

```
<styleUrl>http://localhost/map.kml#myIcon</styleUrl>
```

However, when I try to do that, the map.kml file never gets requested, and the markers don't show up. I've verified that the styleUrl url works.

I'm loading my kml using:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.GML('Name', 'kml_path', {
  format: OpenLayers.Format.KML,
    formatOptions: {
      extractStyles: true,
      extractAttributes: true
    },
    projection: map.displayProjection
});
```

There are some tantalizing options called 'styles' and 'styleBaseUrl' in the OpenLayers.Format.KML API, but I cannot find any documentation about what they are for or how to use them.  Does anyone have any experience with these?

Answer (score 2):

One way could be, have a separate SLD external file with styles and apply it to your GML layer.

Take a look at the SLD OpenLayers code example at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sld.html and just replace the example layers with your layer and replace the styles in the sld-tasmania.xml file. This way, you would not need the option extractStyles in the formatOptions.

Comment: i really liked this example, very complete and effective.  i was looking for a way to filter dynamic content based on zoom level and im pretty sure this is it.  valeu irmao!

Answer (score 2):

In formatOptions, try adding maxDepth:10 or some such integer.  Here is the api definition.

maxDepth:{Integer} Maximum depth for recursive loading external KML URLs Defaults to 0: do no external fetching

With it defaulting to 0, I would suspect that it downloads 0 external kml files.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't have any experience on KML, so I'm sorry if this is totally off. I just read the code for KML layers, especially the style portions. From your `styleUrl` tag it looks as the `styleBaseUrl` should be `http://localhost/map.kml`, based on the code in KML.js:

parseStyleMaps():

```
this.styles[(options.styleBaseUrl || "") + "#" + id] =
                    this.styles[(options.styleBaseUrl || "") + styleUrl];
```

parseStyles():

```
var styleName = (options.styleBaseUrl || "") + "#" + style.id;
```

The `styles` parameter seems to be initialized and rewritten each time the code reads the data, so that won't do any good I think.

Comment: Is an answer that starts with "I really don't have any experience on KML, so I'm sorry if this is totally off. " really an answer?

Comment: well, I tried to help the poster with the stuff not related to KML after my initial excuse...